# jxl how to add border to a range of cells?

Tags: java, jxl

Is there a way to add border to a range of cells, using JXL? Setting border for one cell at a time is quite tedious.  Choosing a range of cells and merging them works, but not sure how to set border for a bunch of cells at a time.

Comment: could not find any solution for this :(

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, by merging the cells first then add border to one cell

```
sheet.mergeCells(ColumnX, rowX, columnY, rowX);
WritableCellFormat cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat();
cellFormat.setBorder(Border.ALL, BorderLineStyle.THIN);
jxl.write.Label lab11 = new jxl.write.Label(columnX, rowX, "Label", cellFormat);
smrysheet.addCell(lab11);
```

Comment: But if you don't want to merge the cells? This way will cause problems

Comment: He asked if he can merge and set border, i was answering to that.

Answer (score -1):

using WritableCellFormat

```
WritableCellFormat cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat();
cellFormat.setBorder(Border.ALL, BorderLineStyle.THIN);
Label label = new Label(col, row, desc, cellFormat);
sheet.addCell(label);
```

Comment: This works for one cell. How to apply it to a range of cells?

Comment: than add it at every cell

Comment: As OP puts it: it's quite tedious. Especially if you need to set outer borders only